# Check if current device has notch in Extension

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have a `ShareExtension` for my App and I need to know wether the current device has a notch or not.

This function works for the normal application:

```
var hasBottomNotch: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0 > 20
    }
    return false
}
```

Unfortunately I can not use this in my extension:

> 'shared' is unavailable in application extensions for iOS: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
return self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 20
```

BTW you can check model of device if it's over Iphone-X , also you can save that boolean in a shared suite defaults of the main app and check it inside the extension

Comment: 'Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'CGFloat', so the right side is never used'